# 'W' prints out W and "W" prints out $. Why?

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

I'm beginner. I don't know why? I'm using Code::Blocks.Please read the following code:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

If q=**'** W **'**, it prints out **W**. 
If q=**"** W **"**, it prints out **$**.

Comment: You should be getting errors for that. GCC 4.7.2 gives me `error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]` for C++ and `error: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast` for C.

Comment: 'W' is character, "W" is pointer to array of 2 characters ('W' and '\0')

Comment: decide on c or c++, in c++ take a look at strings, in c look for c strings (Arrays of char, and after the last character in your string a 0 Byte (different from the character zero wich is 0x30 for Ascii)follows. That might help clearing up things, otherwise the issue is exactly what @aland described

Comment: Did you happen to swap the bottom images with respect to the upper ones?

By the way printf is expecting a char and that you should pass.

Comment: Could you please convert the screenshots to a text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal `"W"` is not a single `char`, but a null-terminated string consisting of `'W'` and `'\0'`.

One way to get the desired behaviour by assigning to a `const char*` and printing that with `%s`

```
const char* q = "W";
printf("%s", q);
```

As pointed out in comments, you could catch this type of error by increasing your compiler's warning levels.

Answer (score 4):

Statement

```
char q = "W";
```

takes an address of string literal `"W"`, and casts *the value of the address* to `char`, i.e., the least significant byte of the address is assigned to `c`.

In your case, the address of `"W"` could be e.g. `0x12345624`, and it is cast to `0x24`, that is `'$'`.

Comment: Nice answer,this is the case what happening here .

Answer (score 2):

```
char q = "W";
```

Turn on the warning levels, your compiler should complain about this. `'W'` isn't a character, it's a string literal, its type is char[2] (an array of two characters, a 'W' and '\0'.) It decays to a pointer to it's first character and that gets converted to `char`, which just happens to translate to ascii value of '$'.

To print string literals the correct format specifier is `%s`.